# Determine if the set $\{(x, \alpha, \beta) \mid x \ge 0 \land 0 \le \alpha \le \pi \land 0 \le \beta \le 2 \pi\}$ is compact

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> Determine if the set $$\{(x, \alpha, \beta) \mid x  \ge 0 \land 0 \le
>  \alpha  \le \pi, 0 \le \beta \le 2 \pi\}$$ is compact

I tried to solve this right from the definition of a compact set. A set is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded. 
I guess that this set can be represented by an "infinitely long" cuboid - namely, with the sides of $x$, $\pi$ and $2 \pi$. If this set were bounded, we would be able to find a sphere centered at the origin containing the whole set. Now, imagine that such sphere does exist and that its radius is $R$. This point: $(R+1, 0, 0)$ is a member of the set in question but is outside the sphere. 
Therefore, the set is not bounded. 
Since it is not bounded, it is not compact. 
 
Please, excuse me if this problem was too simple, but I have only just started my topology course and this is the very first problem I have come across - I'm willing to understand the basics very well. 

Is my solution to the problem correct?

Comment: As a subset of $\mathbf{R}^3$ with the standard topology?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti Yes

Comment: Note that compact = closed and bounded is not the definition. It's a theorem that states an equivalence (which holds in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but not in all metric spaces). But always: a set which is not closed or not bounded (in a metric space) indeed cannot be compact. And this is what you need, as the set is unbounded in the $x$-direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\text{ }$
Yes, everything correct.
$\text{ }$